# Safari on iOS 11 has a "Create PDF" tool that can turn .doc and .ppt files into PDF's, is this available to developers?

Tags: ios, pdf, safari, ios11

Safari on iOS 11 has a "Create PDF/Markup as PDF" tool that can turn webpages, .doc, and .ppt files into PDF's, is this functionality available to developers? I think this feature previously existed (and still exists) as "Send to iBooks", but unlike the new feature it doesn't allow you access to the actual PDF file.

I'm asking because I want a way to import word documents into my app and turn them into PDF's.

Comment: maybe u can try UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData?

Comment: looks like that uses a pdf and turns it into data. I want it the other way round